# another accepts_nested_attributes_for issue - not deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

Not sure why I keep having issues with this. Anyway, here are the models:

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :coupon_codes, :dependent => :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :coupon_codes, :allow_destroy => true, 
                        :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs['code'].blank? }
end


class CouponCode < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :coupon
end
```

The view (using formtastic):

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @coupon] do |f| %>

  <%= f.inputs "Codes" do %>
    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :coupon_codes do |coupon_code| %>
        <% unless coupon_code.object.new_record? %>
            <%= coupon_code.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean %>
        <% else %>
        <%= coupon_code.input :code %>
        <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
 <%= f.buttons %>
<% end %>
```

The post call to the controller:

```
Started POST "/admin/coupons/12" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Apr 02 14:18:47 +0200 2011
Processing by Admin::CouponsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update Coupon", "coupon"=>{"name"=>"Test2", 
"coupon_codes_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"13"}, "1"=>{"code"=>"Silly4"}}, 
"available"=>"true", "num_free_months"=>"0", "auto_generate_codes"=>"false", 
"num_codes"=>"", "num_discount_months"=>"999", "discount_type"=>"value", 
"code_prefix"=>"", "users_per_code"=>"10", "monthly_discount"=>"5.0"}, 
"authenticity_token"=>"f2lPUs2bsDBwlTtNJP63+gnub04nz8PR/+NKzs7ZY9Y=", "utf8"=>"✓", 
"id"=>"12", "_destroy"=>"0"}
```

Now, I noticed a spurious _destroy parameter at the end there. So I changed the form code to:

```
<%= coupon_code.input :_destroy, :as => :select, :include_blank => false, :collection => [ ["No", 0], ["Yes", 1] ] %>
```

To get around that bug. And now I see:

```
Started POST "/admin/coupons/12" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Apr 02 14:25:56 +0200 2011
Processing by Admin::CouponsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update Coupon", "coupon"=>{"name"=>"Test2", 
"coupon_codes_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"13", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"14", 
"_destroy"=>"0"}, "2"=>{"code"=>""}}, "available"=>"true", "num_free_months"=>"0", 
"auto_generate_codes"=>"false", "num_codes"=>"", "num_discount_months"=>"999", 
"discount_type"=>"value", "code_prefix"=>"", "users_per_code"=>"10", 
"monthly_discount"=>"5.0"}, 
"authenticity_token"=>"f2lPUs2bsDBwlTtNJP63+gnub04nz8PR/+NKzs7ZY9Y=", "utf8"=>"✓", 
"id"=>"12"}
```

But still... nothing gets deleted!

I am sure it is something simple, but, I am setting allow_destroy... what else needs to be there!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe issue is that you use

```
:reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs['code'].blank? }
```

And then you send this data:

```
{"id"=>"13", "_destroy"=>"1"}
```

so this `reject_if` "validation" return false, because `code` is blank.

What you need is to also pass `code` in your form:

```
<% unless coupon_code.object.new_record? %>
  <%= coupon_code.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean %>
  <%= coupon_code.input :code, :as => :hidden %> # or how it use hidden field with formastic
<% else %>
  <%= coupon_code.input :code %>
<% end %>
```

or to change your `reject_if`

```
:reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs['code'].blank? && !(attrs[:_destroy] == "true" || attrs[:_destroy] == "1") }
```

last solution little cleaner

Comment: No, that makes no difference. FYI this is a Rails 3 app, running under 3.0.3